# Unable to shrink Ubuntu partition because it's full (when it actually isn't)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I currently have Ubuntu installed on my laptop. I've installed it a few weeks ago, and it's the only operating system in my computer.

Now I would like to install Windows 8.1 in dual boot with Ubuntu, and in order to do so, I need first to reserve some space in the Hard Drive for the Windows installation.

The problem is that through Gparted I was unable to reduce my current Ubuntu partition, as it says it to be full, when it actually isn't (it has around around 600GB free). The option to resize is available, though the maximum and minimum sizes are equal to it's total size. I've tried booting Ubuntu and running Gparted from a live USB, but was unable to reduce the partition because of the same problem.

Since I'm new to the forum, I don't have enough "reputation" to post pictures, but for those who might help and would like to take a look, I've uploaded a screenshot of Gparted on this link:

[image]

What could be the reason Gparted sees the partition as full, and how could I reduce my volume in order to make room for Windows?

Obs: I saw some forums where they said to edit the partition using LVM, though it did not run once installed (graphical errors I think), but even when using it, would I be able to create a primary partition for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are using LVM, so this is not just as simple as resizing a partition in gparted.

What you are seeing in gparted is not a plain partition but an LVM physical volume.  This is an area of space on the disk reserved for LVM to put its logical volumes.  Then, inside those logical volumes are the partitions your system uses.  However, gparted doesn't see these, it just sees one big physical volume which it doesn't know how to edit or move.  Instead, you use the LVM tools to see and manage the logical volumes inside.

The good news is that you can resize and physically move around your logical volumes quite easily using LVM and you can even do this while the system is running.  The bad news is that actually moving or resizing the LVM physical volume around them is quite difficult.

The "LVM way" of doing this would be to set up a new physical volume on a new drive, add it to the same volume group, then live migrate the logical volume to the other drive.  Then, with the physical volume on the original drive now unused, you can remove it from the volume group, and then you can trash that physical volume and re-create it.  The reason I call this the "LVM way" of doing it is that it ensures zero downtime - it can be done on a live system, especially if it has the ability to hotswap in a new drive.  Of course, the downside of doing all this is that it's really slow to migrate all that to a second drive, and that it requires a second drive, so the main benefit is only to people who want to do it on a live system without shutting down.

That said, if you are confident with messing with the partition table yourself, you *can* take a short-cut, with the help from the `pvresize` tool which can resize an LVM physical volume (but only if you also change its size in the partition table manually).  It's not an easy process.  You'll first need to shrink the filesystem in the logical volume, then shrink its logical volume to match, and migrate the remaining extent so that the free space in the volume group is all at the end of that physical volume if necessary.  The included LVM tools will help this far.  Then, work out how much you can shrink the physical volume, change its size in the partition table and simultaneously update its size in LVM with `pvresize`.

The exact procedure is detailed here:

https://serverfault.com/a/419279

If you do go this route, I'd recommend a backup because it will be very easy to screw up and lose data.  And if you're doing a backup anyway, you may as well just do things the old fashioned way and copy everything off the drive, delete the partition and start again, then copy everything back instead.

It's reasons like this I don't recommend LVM for anyone, unless they know they need it and can deal with this stuff.  If you don't absolutely need to be able to hotswap in a new drive, migrate one or more partitions to it, deactivate and remove the old drive, all on a live system without shutting down or rebooting, then (in my opinion) LVM is not really relevant to your needs, and the old fashioned way (plain partitions) will be easier, due to fewer levels of abstraction (easier to get your head around) and tools like gparted which can easily modify and resize them.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it does seem to be the case. I remember now that as I installed Ubuntu it gave me the option to install it as an LVM, and I selected it.